# Why MailChimp doesnt work? my code here

Tags: php, mailchimp

**index.php code:**

```
<form  role="form" action="form.php" method="post">
          <input type="email" id="emailSub" placeholder="Enter your Email Adress" size="30">
          <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn">
</form>
```

**form.php code:**

```
<?php
include_once 'MailChimp.php';

$alertclass = 'alert-warning';
$msg = '';
$email = '';

if (isset($POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['emailSub'])) {
        $msg = 'Please enter a email address.';
    } else {
        $email = filter_var($_POST['emailSub'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $mc = new MailChimp('MY-API-KEY');
        $result = $mc->call('lists/subscribe', array(
                'id'                => 'MY-LIST-ID',
                'email'             => array('email'=>$email),
                'double_optin'      => true,
                'update_existing'   => false,
                'replace_interests' => false,
                'send_welcome'      => false
            )
        );
        if (!empty($result['euid'])) {
            $msg = 'Thanks, please check your mailbox and confirm the subscription.';
            $alertclass = 'alert-success';
        } else {
            if (isset($result['status'])) {
                switch ($result['code']) {
                    case 214:
                    $msg = 'You\'re already a member of this list.';
                    break;
                    default:
                    $msg = 'An unknown error occurred.';
                    $alertclass = 'alert-error';
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        echo $msg;
    }
}
?>
```

I upload it to a server who supports a version of 5.4 PHP so its should work, but it doesnt. Nothing happened, no adding subscribes to my mailchimp list and even not a messages or something. and I dont know why. Any ideas?

Comment: Its wrote me that it doesnt find the MailChimp Class...

Comment: Enable full error reporting and either send error messages to screen or check error logs.

Comment: How should I do it? @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: E.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'MailChimp' not found on line 13 @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Do you have define that class?

Comment: Yes of course... I dont know why it shows it @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: It's not that I don't trust you but the error means what it says: PHP cannot find a class with that name.

Comment: I'd change your `include_once` to a `require` and see what happens.

Comment: A failed `include` should trigger a warning... as long as full error reporting is enabled.